# Hide some tools from React Draft Wysiwyg text editor toolbar

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Is there any way to hide some unnecessary tools from the React Draft Wysiwyg toolbar and change the toolbar order?

Editor:

```
<Editor
  editorState={editorState}
  onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
  wrapperClassName="custom-rich-text-editor-wrapper"
  editorClassName="custom-rich-text-editor"
  toolbarClassName="custom-rich-text-editor-toolbar"
  toolbar={toolbar}
  }}
/>
```

Toolbar:

```
   const toolbar = {
      list: { inDropdown: true },
      inline: {
        inDropdown: false,
        className: undefined,
        component: undefined,
        dropdownClassName: undefined,
        options: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
      },
      fontSize: {}
   };
```

Expecting toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fond the answer:

there is a `options` property

```
<Editor
  editorState={editorState}
  onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
  wrapperClassName="custom-rich-text-editor-wrapper"
  editorClassName="custom-rich-text-editor"
  toolbarClassName="custom-rich-text-editor-toolbar"
  toolbar={
    {options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize']}
  }
/>
```

Comment: This worked for me! I didn't see any doc about that. Thanks